# Trigger action realtime based on keyword in Logs

Tags: log-analysis

I have a requirement for which I want to trigger an action (like calling a REST-ful service) in the event a keyword is found in the logs. The trigger would have to be fairly **real time**. I was evaluating open source solutions like **GrayLog2**, **ELK stack** (which I believe can't analyse real time), **fluentd** etc. but wanted to know your opinion on that. It would be great if the tool also allows setting up rules against key words to eliminate false positives and easy to set up.

I hope this makes sense and apologies if this has been discussed elsewhere!

Comment: At the moment I am evaluating Logstash + Graylog2, but any recommendations will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried Logstash+Graylog2 combination for the scenario I described in the question and it works quite well. I had to tweak a few things to  make Logstash work with Graylog2, especially around capturing the right log levels. I will try this out on a highly loaded clustered environment and update my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Massalyzer. It's a real-time analyzer too, very fast (up to 10 millinon line per sec), and you can analyze unlimited size with free demo version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that and post my findings here.